# JSP compilation error in Jboss 6.4

Tags: jsp, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

Im trying to deploy simple hello world war in the jboss 6.4 server and getting the following error

added the corresponding jars in the module in jboss and referred from war.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package javax.servlet does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package javax.servlet.http does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package javax.servlet.jsp does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package org.apache.jasper.runtime does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package org.apache.jasper.runtime does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JspFactory
  location: class org.apache.jsp.jsp.NewFile_jsp

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package org.glassfish.jsp.api does not exist

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:

Comment: Show your code (and project config, e.g. `pom.xml` file). The most probable cause is you have `org.glassfish.jsp.api` dependency in the code, without adding Glassfish libs to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors i would say it is more than simple helloworld application

This is simple helloworld app [jboss-eap-quickstarts/helloworld at 6.4.x · jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts · GitHub](http://This%20is%20simple%20helloworld%20app%20jboss-eap-quickstarts/helloworld%20at%206.4.x%20%C2%B7%20jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts%20%C2%B7%20GitHub)

Given you have error messages starting with PWC, I would guess that your application has bundled glassfish jsp compiler which shouldn't be there as it is provided by container.